# How can I change the background color of table cell (td) using two buttons for different colors?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**My HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wolf and Rabbit Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wolf&rabbit_game.css">
    <script src="wolf&rabbit_game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tableCell"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="I'm red" onclick="setColorRed">
<input id="button2" type="button" value="I'm green" onclick="setColorGreen">
</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS file:**
    table{
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }

```
td{
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

#button1,#button2{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-weight: semibold;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 1%;
}

#button1{
    background: red;
}

#button2{
    background: green;
}

body{
    text-align: center;
}

img{
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**My JavaScript file:**

```
function setColor(){
  if ("#button1").click {
    document.getElementById("#tableCell").style.backgroundColor="red";
  };
  if ("#button2").click {
    document.getElementById("#tableCell").style.backgroundColor="green";
  };
};
```

Comment: it would be useful to explain what you are expecting to see, and what the result is - blindly pasting lots of code with no explanation isn't great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this JS Fiddle

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/exsh5a5b/)

There is no need of calling two different methods on two different buttons, a single method to accept the color parameter and change the desired element's color is good enough.

You have to modify your code like this and make sure javascript code comes before your button markup.

```
<script>
function setColor(color){  
    document.getElementById("tableCell").style.backgroundColor=color;
};
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tableCell">test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="I'm red" onclick="setColor('red')">
<input id="button2" type="button" value="I'm green" onclick="setColor('green')">
```